# Ndepend CQL to query types out of assembly wildcard

Tags: ndepend, cql

In order to determine what low-level framework types a web application is directly using, one has to define each and every assembly involved.

```
SELECT TYPES FROM ASSEMBLIES
"Company.System.Framework",
"Company.System.Framework.ReferenceLookup",
"Company.System.Framework.Web",
"Company.System.Framework.Security",
"Company.System.Framework.Logging",
"Company.System.Framework.DMS"
WHERE IsDirectlyUsedBy "WebAssembly"
```

I cannot find any syntax to wildcard the list of assemblies. Is there no way to shortcut this? We have a lot of framework level assemblies.

i.e. Company.System.Framework.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If filtering types using a namespace regex would be ok in your context, then you could use the following CQL query:

```
SELECT TYPES WHERE IsDirectlyUsedBy "ASSEMBLY:WebAssembly"
AND FullNameLike "Company.System.Framework*"
```

Comment: This works as the namespaces within the assemblies are of common hierarchy. Of course it means keeping tabs on all different framework namespaces that might exist.